# Laravel: How to display the value of other table in a loop?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So, I have this code which is printing the various topics/threads started by the user.

It is looping over the **Posts** table that contains data related to posts.

In **User** column, it will display `user_id`. But I want to access **User** table and display the `user_name` column matching that `user_id`. How to do this?

```
<table border="2">
    <tr>
        <th>Topic</th>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Replies</th>
        <th>Views</th>
        <th>Last Update</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($topics as $topic)
        <tr>
            <td><a href="topics/{{$topic->id}}">{{$topic->topic_title}}</a></td>
            <td>{{$topic->id}}</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>{{$topic->updated_at}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Controller's Code:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $topics = Topic::where('board_id', $id)->get();
        return view('boards.show')->with('topics', $topics);
    }
```

Comment: Check this https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships

Comment: please post your controller and model code if it has proper relationship or not?

Comment: @PrateikDarji Added.

Comment: @DeepakRawat does your topic table have any reference to user table?

Comment: @PrateikDarji It has a column name 'user_id' that matches the 'user_id' column of user table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In controller [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) user model:

```
$topics = Topic::where('board_id', $id)->with('user')->get();
```

In view:

```
<td>{{ $topic->user->user_name }}</td>
```

I assume you already have the `user` relationship defined in `Topic` model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
@foreach($topics as $topic)
    @php $user = DB::table('User')->where('id', $topic->id)->first(); @endphp;
    <tr>
        <td><a href="topics/{{$topic->id}}">{{$topic->topic_title}}</a></td>          
        <td>{{ $user }}</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>{{$topic->updated_at}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: _$user_ will print the array of instead of printing `user_name` only and this is not a good method of getting data, data should be loaded in the controller itself.

Comment: Because Ali used `->get()` not `->first()`,and need to change `{{ $user }}` to `{{ $user->name }}`, BTW, using query in blade is not good practice, create a relation for this

Answer (score 0):

In your **Post** model

```
public function user(){
     $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

In your blade  **{{$topic->user->name}}**

```
<table border="2">
<tr>
    <th>Topic</th>
    <th>User</th>
    <th>Replies</th>
    <th>Views</th>
    <th>Last Update</th>
</tr>
@foreach($topics as $topic)
    <tr>
        <td><a href="topics/{{$topic->id}}">{{$topic->topic_title}}</a></td>
        <td>{{$topic->user->name}}</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>{{$topic->updated_at}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define relation in models first like this:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\Post");
    }
}

class Post extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\User");
    }
}
```

then in the loop on the view side you can access user's data like this:

```
@foreach($topics as $topic)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$topic->user->name}}</td>

    </tr>
@endforeach
```

You do not need to use "with" function in this case. you only need to fetch topics, pass them on to view, iterate through and you get the user's data